# How do I export an entire database from Oracle 10 and import it to Oracle 11.2.0 with all users?

Tags: java, database, oracle

I have got  Oracle 10 on A computer and there I have got a database centt.
On B computer I have got installed Oracle 11.2.0 and there is no database.
The name of the database on A computer is centt and there I have also some users like stt, wnn, tnn, etc.
Now I would like to export entire database from A computer with all users to file (e.g. allDBdump.dat).
Then I would like to import this database (file allDBdump.dat) to B computer.
I have used export command like below on A computer:

```
exp userid=sys/sys file='c:\allDBdump.dat' log='c:\allDBdump.log' FULL=Y
```

Now I would like to import entire database on A computer with all users.
I know that before import I need to create a database on A computer, by "Database Configuration Assistant".
Then I need to create all users in sql tool by commands:

```
CREATE USER st IDENTIFIED BY st;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO st WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO st WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Then I use command to import database:

```
imp 'sys/sys@192.168.61.62:1521/centt as sysdba' FULL=Y file=allDBdump.dat fromuser=st touser=st
```

This solution is good, but I need to know all users before import.
The question is how to do it, how to import allDBdump.dat without creating all users on A computer.
Something like:

```
imp 'sys/sys@192.168.61.62:1521/centt as sysdba' FULL=Y file=allDBdump.dat IMPORT_ENTIRE_DATABASE_WITH_ALL_USERS_ON_A_COMPUTER
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use impdp/expdp instead of exp/imp. There are several things that exp/imp won't handle correctly in newer versions of Oracle (e.g. contexts).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Datapump](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g) ?. It's much better. Only drawback it's that you'll need a directory on both the servers  (or link them with db_link)

```
expdp system/password@db10g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G.log

impdp system/password@db11g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=impdpDB11G.log
```

Comment: I have tried something like this:
expdp 'sys/sys@dba as sysdba' full=Y 'directory=D:\tmpFolder' dumpfile=dump.dmp logfile=dump.log
And I have got an error:
LRM-00105: 'directory=D:\tmpFolder' doesn't allow for logic value for full

Comment: @user2856064 You need to specify a database directory. Look for them on `select * from SYS.ALL_DIRECTORIES;` You should, at least, have DATA_PUMP_DIR that it's default directory for expdp/impdp

Comment: @user2856064 How did it go?